# Python 2.7, unicode - ordinal not in range

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to write a string pulled from an xml file to another file (HTML), but when I try an run the script it gives me this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 124: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the Python code:

```
f = open('web/tv.html', 'a')
counter = 0
for showname in os.listdir('xml/additional'):
    tree = et.parse('xml/additional/%s/en.xml' % showname)
    root = tree.getroot()
    series = root.find('Series')
    description = series.find('Overview').text
    cell = '\n<tr><td>' + showname + '</td><td>' + description + '</td></tr>'
    f.write(cell)
f.append(u'</table></div></body></html>')
```

This is a sample of the XML file:

```
<Series>
  <Overview>From Emmy Award-winner Dan Harmon comes &quot;Community&quot;, a smart comedy series about higher education – and lower expectations. The student body at Greendale Community College is made up of high-school losers, newly divorced housewives, and old people who want to keep their minds active. Within these not-so-hallowed halls, Community focuses on a band of misfits, at the center of which is a fast-talkin' lawyer whose degree has been revoked, who form a study group and end up learning a lot more about themselves than they do about their course work.</Overview>
  <other>stuff</other>
</Series>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I find Unicode mightily complicated.

Comment: `f.append` should fail on a file object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Unicode with bytestrings; the XML results are Unicode values with, among other things, an [en dash character](http://codepoints.net/U+2013). The result cannot be written to a plain text file without encoding first.

Encode your `description` to ASCII text with:

```
description = description.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

which uses HTML entities for any codepoint beyond ASCII:

```
>>> description = u'... a smart comedy series about higher education – and lower expectations.'
>>> description.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'... a smart comedy series about higher education &#8211; and lower expectations.'
```